# In vim, how do I define a function that can be called without :call?

Tags: function, vim

How do I define a function so that I can call it from command-line mode without :call in front of it?

Right now, I have to do this: `:call TrimWhitespace()`

I want to define it so that I can do this: `:TrimWhitespace`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This won't be a function, you should create a command instead. Check the documentation for [commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#user-commands) (`:help user-commands` in Vim).

The simplest case is of a command to call a function:

```
command! TrimWhitespace call TrimWhitespace()
```